# How do you tell if a connection string belongs to MySql or SQL Server?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, connection-string

Is there a way to test if a connection string is valid without attempting to open a connection?

I need to find out if a connection string is a MySql connection string, or a SQL Server connection string?

**Edit**

Here's what I've tried

```
var connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"

MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mySqlBuilder;
try { mySqlBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString); }
catch { mySqlBuilder = null; }

SqlConnectionStringBuilder msSqlBuilder;
try { msSqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString); }
catch { msSqlBuilder = null; }
```

Both `mySqlBuilder` and `msSqlBuilder` will take the connection string with no exception thrown.

Also, `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.ToString()` returns `server=myServerAddress;database=myDataBase;user id=myUsername;password=myPassword`

Comment: It might be impossible in some circumstances.

Comment: For example if you use DNS format, there is no way to tell as the details are stored elsewhere.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev Let me clarify, I only have a string, formatted correctly to be put into a MySqlConnectionStringBuilder or MsSqlConnectionStringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you are connecting, if you specify a username and password in the connection string then there is a difference:

MS SQL Server connection string using username/password:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

MySql connection string using username/password:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

So you could check if the connection string contains `Password` or `Pwd`.

Comment: What if a userid and password aren't specified? Does MsSql require IntegratedSecurity be specified? **Edit:** I suppose it doesn't matter since, AFAIK, MySql *must* have a Uid and Password to be valid.

Comment: For MS SQL, I think you either need Integrated or username/password. Afaik, MySql only supports username/password.

Comment: I was hopeful, but apparently this won't work. It looks like `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.ToString` returns in the format `server=myServerAddress;database=myDataBase;user id=myUsername;password=myPassword`

Comment: @TrevorPilley Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword; also work with MS SQL.